# MySQL Workbech execute button desactiveted

Tags: mysql-workbench

why this button is disactivated? I try to execute my query
thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are not connected or the server went down.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem as a beginner some time ago and I have found out the best way to solve it. So let's get started...

Those buttons become deactivated when the instance is not connected to the server on your computer (Shows **unconnected** in the top left corner)

Go to the **home** of the MySQL Workbench by clicking the home icon in the top left corner

Then click on a connection in **MySQL connections** section

Enter the ROOT password you created in the installation.
hen you will be in a new instance and the buttons have activated

If there is no connections in the connections section click the "+" mark and create one

At least there is one connection all the time

The problem should be solved by now.

**# Make sure to upvote if this is helpful**